# Playing audio file with MediaPlayer

Tags: android, audio, media-player

Hi there I'm an android and java newbie and is wondering if there is a better way of doing the following:

I currently have 250 short audio files (.3gp) that i put inside my res/raw folder and based on a certain condition,  I want to play certain audio file.  For example if the text of the button that is being clicked is the word "and", I want to play the and.3gp sound file.

The following is the code that I use to accomplish what I want to do:

```
if(word.equals("No"))
{   
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(HomeActivity.this,R.raw.no);
    mp.start();
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(listener );
}
else if(word.equals("And"))
{
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(HomeActivity.this,R.raw.and);
    mp.start();
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(listener );
}

.....
```

The above code is working fine so far but I'm wondering if I can do this without having a 250 else if condition.  Is there a way to pass in the audio file to MedialPlayer.Create by file name via Uri?  If yes, how do I do it?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a hash function that maps a string key to the uri

Comment: it looks like i might be able to do this by doing something similar to this http://www.41post.com/1301/programming/how-to-get-android-local-files-uri  Thanks. I will try this tonight.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through all your files in your raw folder and remove the file extension, then test against that.